# How can I constrain the width of a child within an inline-block element?

Tags: css

How can I constrain the width of a child within an `inline-block` element?

Assume that I am targeting newest browsers.

Given an element displayed using `inline-block`, how can I constrain a child element so that it does not scale beyond the parent's witch.

In practical terms, I am trying to built a system that will take an image of any width and keep the caption constrained to the width of the parent container:

- without having to specify width
- without using jQuery or other DOM manipulation

**CSS**

```
<style>
div {
    width:800px;
    background-color:silver;
    text-align: center;
}
figure {
    display:inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}
figcaption {
    background-color:pink;
}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <figure>
        <img src="http://i.techrepublic.com.com/blogs/11062012figure_a.gif" />
        <figcaption>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried `figure > * { max-width: 100%; }` ?

Comment: `max-width:100%` would do the trick. But it would be the width of `div`, which is the only who actually has a set `width`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by applying [`contain: inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain#inline-size) to `figcaption`. This is slightly counterintuitive considering that `figure` is the *contain*er here, but it is `figcaption` that must ignore the inline size of its contents.

```css
div {
    width: 800px;
    background-color: silver;
    text-align: center;
}

figure {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: orange;
    padding: 1em;
    margin: 0;
}

figcaption {
    contain: inline-size;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <figure>
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OM9kD.png" />
        <figcaption>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion adding the following code can help you:

```
figure {width: 100%;}
img {width: 100%;}
```

In any case if you want to do this only with CSS, then you need play with percentages.

Comment: The idea is that I want the width of the image to dictate the width of the figure container and the caption. Setting both to 100% will work, but that removes and variation in image width.